# Giving up protections for balance billing in hospitals

Tags: united-states, consumer-protection, medical, bill-of-rights

In certain states, one is protected from balance billing for emergency, hospital, and ambulatory services. Balance billing is when one is surprised that an out-of-network doctor/group bills rack rate for services provided by team of in-network and out-of-network providers.

Though, I have noted online that one may give written consent to give up these protections. Why would one sign such a document to give up these protections, and how would such a document be worded?

And at least in emergency settings, I would hope throwing a bunch of papers in front of someone in pain giving up such protections would not hold up in court.

Comment: "I would hope throwing a bunch of papers in front of someone in pain giving up such protections would not hold up in court." Your hopes aren't likely to be fulfilled. Usually that would hold up.

Comment: American courts are mostly there to protect investment property, not you.